# some questions about game development

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

I'm a web developer, I also love games, but I really don't know anything about game development. Recently I've decided to write an outline document about an idea. 
I've got a few questions to get me started, mostly I'm looking for terminology (or resources) to be able to research.

1. How to come up with a fair cost/gather, attack/defence/health and other ratios in a game?

   1.1 is it just trial and error or there is a mathematical solution for these things?

   1.2 what is the terminology for these things? what do you call them?

   1.3 what area these things go into? (game designe, mechanics, etc)

   1.4 what are the keywords for research and googling on these topics? (I believe 1.1 answers this too)
2. Is there a way to estimate development cost (in terms of time and team number)?
3. Is selecting a time scale for in-game by trial and error?
4. How to decide what requirments should be for the upgrade system? I mean, is there a solution or these things are just by tase?
5. what are the steps when developing a game and what to think of in each step? (I really just need resources)
6. most importantly, should I even worry about these things when crafting the idea? if not, which step of development should be dedicated to these things?

Comment: This question is likely too broad for this site. You might want to consider splitting this into a few distinct questions, although a number of these may be things that simply come with experience, are opinion-based or are too specific to any given game to give a general answer to. If you have a concrete idea which you're having some trouble implementing (for example, in terms of an upgrade system), you may get better answers by giving the specifics of that and basing the question on that.

Comment: To briefly address parts of your question: look into "balancing" and read [What should be created first in a video game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130499/what-should-be-created-first-in-a-video-game). You can also take a look at some of the questions under the [tag:balance] tag.

Comment: The way StackExchange works is to ask one question per question post. You can't accept more than one answer to a single post, so each post needs to be tightly focused on one specific issue - which also tends to attract deeper and more useful/actionable answers, faster, than questions with a broader or fuzzier topic. With regard to your questions about balancing and determining requirements for a system, I recommend checking out [this previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/170279/39518) and [the Game Design tag guidance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-design/info).

Comment: ok, thank you all, I'll try to split up this question into several smaller questions.

Comment: I think you can leave it up, I find these things interesting, and often times people will leave answers in the comments :)

Comment: 1.0 I think the most important thing to decide for this is Player Experience.  Do you want the player to feel frantic, relaxed, invincible?  is it a run and gun experience? puzzle? Is it about fighting bosses or fighting armies of easy to kill enemies or both? etc.  Once you have this, it will be easier to design a combat system

Comment: also, I think a good idea with health is to come up with a starting health system.  for instance:  the players lazers can take off 1 health of each monster.  their are five levels of monster difficulty, starting off at 5 health.  the difficult levels go like this. 5, 8, 10, 12,15.  I want the player to be frantic, so he has ten health, and any monster can take off 1 health, but bigger monsters can sometimes take off up to five.  I could start of with this health system, and then fine tune it if the game doesn't feel right.  you can do that for loots of different things, like gather and cost.